# how to use a variable with a GUI in python 3

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get this so when you press 'HELLO' five time the text turn red 
just its not adding any thing on when i add anything to the viable.this is the code.

```
    from tkinter import *
    class application(Frame):
    global t
  t=1  
   def info(self):
      print ("test")
    global t
    t=t+5

  def createWidgets(self):
    global t
    t=t
    self.exet= Button(self)
    self.exet["text"] = "QUIT"
    self.exet["fg"] = "red"
    self.exet["command"] = self.quit

    self.exet.pack({"side": "left"})

    self.hi = Button(self)
    self.hi["text"] = "HELLO",
    if t == 5:
        self.hi["fg"] = "red"

    self.hi["command"] = self.info
    self.hi.pack({"side": "left"})

  def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.pack()
    self.createWidgets()
```

Thanks to anyone helps!

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, can you please clean that up?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems here: First, you use a global variable and then you include it within the scope of your functions. Instead of this, you should use an instance variable (`self.t`, or even `self.counter` for better readability). Secondly, you are checking the value of the counter in `createWidgets`, which is only called once by the `__init__` method. You should increase and check its value in the event handler function on the button.

```
class application(Frame):

    def info(self):
        self.counter += 1
        print(self.counter)
        if self.counter == 5:
            self.hi["fg"] = "red"

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.exet= Button(self)
        self.exet["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.exet["fg"] = "red"
        self.exet["command"] = self.quit
        self.exet.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.hi = Button(self)
        self.hi["text"] = "HELLO",
        self.hi["command"] = self.info
        self.hi.pack({"side": "left"})

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
```